# Rails UJS "on" for handling ajax event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I'm using the jQuery method "on" in a Rails app to attach an event on a form which doesn't always exist. It doesn't seem to be attaching an event handler when #myForm is appended to the document.

Here is UJS's suggested usage of `on()`:

```
$("#myForm").on("ajax:complete", function(xhr, status) { ... }
```

Here is how I usually implement jQuery's `on()`, but this does not seem to work:

```
$("body").on("ajax:complete", "#myForm", function(xhr, status) {...}
```

Rails UJS wiki: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: The second argument `element` is optional... it is used for event delegation

Comment: If you're voting to close - it's likely something obvious, please let me know :)

Comment: @MattBall - turns out it is Rails related. Rails comes with a library called UJS.

Comment: Those are just the events. The JavaScript event binding API is simply jQuery. In what way are you trying to bind event handlers with the 3-argument version of `.on()` that "doesn't work?" Please show the code you're trying to get working.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Which browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UJS doesn't really have much to do with the `on` function. That's provided by jQuery, and it takes multiple forms. UJS simply fires the `ajax:complete` event so you can hook into it yourself.

The `selector` argument is optional, so both

```
$(...).on("ajax:complete", function(xhr, status) { ... }
```

and

```
$(...).on("ajax:complete", "form", function(xhr, status) { ... }
```

are valid uses, though they work somewhat differently.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful links:

[Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

[Understanding delegation .on()](http://jqapi.com/#p=on)

```
$(selector).on(event,childSelector,data,function,map)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the links @Tyagi - they don't seem to address the issue about UJS and 2 vs 3 arguments. Thanks though :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Hope this will shed the light.