# Rails 4 UJS to properly combine ajax events in a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dom-events

I am new to rails and I'm trying to wrap my head around the proper usage of rails UJS events versus using something like jQuery for handling event states in an ajax request.

Usually I simply initiate an action based on an element id, class or data-attribute. In jQuery I would use something like this to initiate an ajax call after the event is initiated. The function could include event handling for various states. Easy enough.

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: datastr,
   type: "GET",
   beforeSend : function() {
     do somethign beforehand
   },      
   error: function(n) {
     /* if we have an error try submitting without ajax */
     do something if an error
     return false;
   },
   success: function(m){
     do something if successful
   }
});
```

In rails, however, there is a method that can be applied to forms or links etc that tell rails to initiate an ajax requests automatically (`"data-remote="true"`). This works fine but I want to do things based on the state of the request. I understand that you can use UJS which is a scripting adaptor of jQuery for rails to handle these events as answered here:

[Rails UJS "on" for handling ajax event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486433/rails-ujs-on-for-handling-ajax-event)

What's not clear to me is how I can combine these into one function. All the examples I've seen show these calls separately for each event which seems kludgy to me.

So handling an event for say a form with data remote true:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="/controller" data-remote="true">
```

Instead of doing this separately:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myform').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    do something
  });

  $('#myform').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings) {
    do something
  });
});
```

I want to do something like this but I keep getting errors.

```
$(function() {
   $("#myform").on('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {
       doSomething();
     }).on('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {
       dosomething();
     });
     }).on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
       dosomething();
     });
   });
});
```

Lastly if I just use plain unobtrusive JavaScript or jQuery to initiate the action shouldn't I remove the `data-remote="true"` on the form? If not wouldn't this potentially trigger the request more than once?

Comment: Be a bit more specify please - "but I keep getting errors" what errors?

Comment: Hi max thank you for the response. I apologize. I am getting the following error. Its some syntax issue.

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'`
`});`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one extra "});" ? Try this one:

```
$(function() {
   $("#myform").on('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {
       doSomething();
     }).on('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {
       dosomething();
     }).on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
       dosomething();
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Yen-Ju. I tried this as well and it still gives me the error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
});

ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("#myform").on('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {
    doSomething();
  }).on('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {
    dosomething();
  }).on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
    dosomething();
  });
});
```

There where a few extra brackets and parens in there.

> Lastly if I just use plain unobtrusive JavaScript or jquery to
>   initiate the action shouldn't I remove the data-remote="true" on the
>   form? If not wouldn't this potentially trigger the request more than
>   once?

Well lets put it this way - if you add an event handler which sends the form with ajax to the form submit event or clicking the submit button you should not use `data-remote="true"` since it will cause two AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I figured that. I did try removing the colon still getting the SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
 

});

Comment: This may be a UJS thing but maybe chaining like this wont work. Doing it this way works  I'm not sure if this is a UJS specific thing, but doing it this way without chaining events works for me. `$(function() {
  $("#myform").on('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {
    dosomething();
  });
  
  $("#myform").on('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {
    dosomething();
    
  });
 
  $("#myform").on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
     dosomething();
  });
});`

Comment: It don't think it has anything to do with UJS. I think you just might be doing something else wrong. jQuery.on returns the jQuery object for chaining. See the example I have added above.

Comment: That's probably true. I just cant figure out why chaining them like this is causing my errors. The only difference for me is that I'm utilizing it with rails UJS ajax events. For now having them separate works for me. Thanks again for your help.